# Show All Columns In a Tibble In Console Output

Tags: r

How can I view the remaining 3 variables within the console output?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

```
calib_tbl %>% modeltime_accuracy() %>%
print(width=Inf)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `print(n=6)` or whatever number of rows you want to see.
Here is an example with the `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(tibble)
mtcars %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    print(n=50)
```

```
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6 258     110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8 360     175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6 225     105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8 360     245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
11  17.8     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
12  16.4     8 276.    180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
13  17.3     8 276.    180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
14  15.2     8 276.    180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
15  10.4     8 472     205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
16  10.4     8 460     215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
17  14.7     8 440     230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
18  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1
19  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
20  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1
21  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1
22  15.5     8 318     150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     3     2
23  15.2     8 304     150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2
24  13.3     8 350     245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4
25  19.2     8 400     175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     3     2
26  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1
27  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
28  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2
29  15.8     8 351     264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4
30  19.7     6 145     175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6
31  15       8 301     335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
32  21.4     4 121     109  4.11  2.78  18.6     1     1     4     2
```

Comment: I wanted to print all columns, got the answer here>> https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html . In my code, it would become: calib_tbl %>% modeltime_accuracy() %>%print(width=Inf)

Comment: In the end it is with is `print`.